# Magento 2: How to add optgroup to select dropdown

Tags: magento2, ui-select

In my `ui-select fields` I want to sort my options by different optgroups like:
[image]

Source model location is `Vendor/Model/Source/Model.php` and it has the function for options as below

```
public function getAllOptions()
{
    if (empty($this->options)) {
        $options = [];
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $searchResults = $this->ghscategoryRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
        foreach ($searchResults->getItems() as $ghscategory) {
            $options[] = [
                'value' => $ghscategory->getGhscategoryId(),
                'label' => $ghscategory->getGhs_category_code(),
            ];
        }
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    return $this->options;
}
```

Can I edit the options array and add optgroups?

If not here, which file/files I have to edit to add my optgroups?

Comment: Vendor/Model/Source/Model.php path is incomplete, there should be a module name

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Vendor/Modulename/Source/Modulename.php

Comment: But my question is still the same

Answer (score 11):

In same file create your option array like this

```
$optionGroup = [
    [
        'label' => 'Option group1 lable',
        'value' => [
            [
                'label' => 'group 1 option 1',
                'value' => 'group1-value1'
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'group 1 option2',
                'value' => 'group 1 value2'
            ],
        ],
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Option group2 lable',
        'value' => [
            [
                'label' => 'group 2 option 1',
                'value' => 'group2-value1'
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'group 2 option2',
                'value' => 'group2-value2'
            ],
        ],
    ]
];
```

and return this array it will create drop down with option group.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your awnser. I am not sure, where I have to add this code.Do I have to replace the array "options" by the new array "optionGroup"???

Comment: You have to just modify your area structure of $options like I have in my $optionGroup.

Comment: You can also use the my $optionGroup array and return it instead of $options for testing if it will give you perfect output then change the values as you want.

Comment: Thank, the sample is allways working. Now I will try with my values.

Comment: Okay if it's work with your values too then accept the answer so it will help others

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the answer: if you want to add a "Choose" line you only have to add a line at the beginning of your $optionGroup array, like this:

```
$optionGroup = [
    ['value' => "Choose", 'label' => __("Choose...")],
    [
        'label' => 'Option group1 lable',
        'value' => [
            [
                'label' => 'group 1 option 1',
                'value' => 'group1-value1'
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'group 1 option2',
                'value' => 'group 1 value2'
            ],
        ],
    ],
   ...
];
```